# .net Maui, I've defined the shadow property in my ConentPage.Resources but can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my button

Tags: c#, android, maui, shadow

Here's the code, I've setup a Unified Button style that way I don't have to change individual buttons if I'm simply changing colors and applying pressed visual states but can't seem to figure out how to work my shadows in here. I want my buttons to have a shadow below them giving depth.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- Shadows -->
        <Shadow Brush="Black"
                x:Key="Shadow"
            Offset="20,20"
            Radius="40"
            Opacity="0.8" />
        <!-- Unified Button Style -->
        <Style x:Key="UnifiedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#4169E1"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Poppins-Medium"/>
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="TranslationY" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.98" />
                                <Setter Property="TranslationY" Value="2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4169E1" Offset="0.0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#4169E1" Offset="0.5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#4169E1" Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>`

                
<Setter Property="Shadow" HasShadow="True"/>

<Setter Property="Shadow" x:Key="Shadow"/>
```

Not sure why I expected it to work but I'm still learning and a bit lost here. `your text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the shadow property in your style, you could try the following code:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
   <Shadow Brush="Black"
        x:Key="Shadow"
        Offset="10,10"
        Radius="10"
        Opacity="0.8" />
    <!-- Unified Button Style -->
    <Style x:Key="UnifiedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#4169E1"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Poppins-Medium"/>
        <Setter Property="Shadow" Value="{StaticResource Shadow}"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TranslationY" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.98" />
                            <Setter Property="TranslationY" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And better not use LinearGradientBrush, because now the [Shadow Brush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/shadow?view=net-maui-7.0) property only support for now a solid color.

That's the result:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, for whatever reason my CornerRadius though isn't being read anymore by the app.

Comment: Do you mean change this value ```<Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="25"/>``` but with no effect?

Comment: Ignore, I closed the emulator, cleaned and rebuilt and boom. Everything is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: It's my pleasure! Happy coding!